# Matlab program of a finite sum that returns the result in a matrix

Tags: summation, matrix-equations

I am trying to write a simple program for a finite sum from say 0 to 4 of an equation with two variables , say m' and n. each variable takes values form 0 to 4. The result will be in a matrix form and the matrix element corresponds to values of a and b.

That is element A(1,2) will the finite sum of the equation when m' =1 and n=2.

A(m',n)=sum((d^(-1)exp(2(n^2)*i*2*pi/d))(exp(m^2)*i*2*pi/d) - mn + m'n), m=0:4)

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @MaryStar d= 5; >> for k = 0:4; for n = 0:4; f = (d^(-1)*exp(2*(n^2)*i*2*pi/d))*((exp(m^2)*i*2*pi/d) - exp(m*n*i*2*pi/d) + exp(k*n*i*2*pi/d)); A(k,n) = sum(f, m = 0..4);

Comment: This is the error I got before ending the loops Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.

Comment: At the command sum(f, m = 0..4); you mean that $m$ should run from $0$ to $4$, right? Why don't you use another for-loop, for m=0:4 ? You cannot write it m = 0..4.

Comment: @MaryStar You are right. For each element of the matix A to be a sum over m from 0 to 4, where would you suggest i put the for-loop for m?

Comment: You could do it like that:

>> d= 5;
>> for n = 1:4;
for k = 1:4;
for m = 1:4;
A(k,n) = (d^(-1)*exp(2*(n^2)*i*2*pi/d))*((exp(m^2)*i*2*pi/d) - exp(m*n*i*2*pi/d) + exp(k*n*i*2*pi/d));
end
end
end